# Custom entity datetime field in calendar

Tags: views, 8, entities, datetime

I created an entity in a module, using code. I generated skeletons with `drupal console generate:entity:content` (without bundles), and then added a datetime field to my TestFieldEntityItem.php, in `baseFieldDefinitions()`.

```
$fields['test_date'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('datetime')
  ->setLabel(t('Test date'))
  ->setDescription(t('Test.'))
  ->setRevisionable(TRUE)
  ->setSettings([
    'datetime_type' => 'date'
  ])
  ->setDefaultValue('')
  ->setDisplayOptions('view', [
    'label' => 'above',
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'settings' => [
      'format_type' => 'medium',
    ],
    'weight' => 14,
  ])
  ->setDisplayOptions('form', [
    'type' => 'datetime_default',
    'weight' => 14,
  ])
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
  ->setDisplayConfigurable('view', TRUE);
```

I installed my module, cleared the cache, reinstalled calendar and calendar_datetime modules, but when I try to add a view from a template, like the calendar module suggests, I can't see any template matching my datetime field.

If I create a datetime field on this entity through the UI, it appears in view templates. What am I missing?

Inspecting the calendar code, I found the function that search datetime fields, in [ViewsFieldTemplate.php](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/calendar/tree/src/Plugin/Derivative/ViewsFieldTemplate.php?h=8.x-1.x#n114).
This function finds my field, but the field_info does not match `isDateField()` because of the `argument` property.

isDateField() wants 'datetime' as argument ID.

```
protected function isDateField($field_info) {
  if (!empty($field_info['field']['id']) && $field_info['field']['id'] == 'field') {
    if (!empty($field_info['argument']['id']) && $field_info['argument']['id'] == 'date') {
      return TRUE;
    }
  }
  return FALSE;
}
```

My field_info argument is 'string'.

```
array (size=7)
  'title' => ...
  'help' => ...
  'field' => 
      'id' => string 'field' (length=5)
  'argument' => 
      'id' => string 'string' (length=6)
  'filter' => 
      'id' => string 'string' (length=6)
  'sort' => 
      'id' => string 'standard' (length=8)
  'entity field' => string 'test_date' (length=4)
```

So thanks to @4k4 answer, I tried to do the same as the working date field, and I created my own EntityViewsData (I tried hook_views_data_alter() first but the field was not present in input data)

```
namespace Drupal\kabukis_tests\Entity;
use Drupal\views\EntityViewsData;

class TestEntityViewsData extends EntityViewsData {
  public function getViewsData() {
    $additionalData = [
      'test_date' => [
        'title' => new TranslatableMarkup('Birth date'),
        'help' => new TranslatableMarkup('Birth date'),
        'field' => [ 'id' => 'field' ],
        'argument' => [ 'id' => 'date' ],
        'filter' => [ 'id' => 'date' ],
        'sort' => [ 'id' => 'date' ],
        'entity field' => 'test_date',
      ]
    ];
    $data['test_field_entity_field_data'] = array_merge($data['test_field_entity_field_data'], $additionalData);
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Now, the field appears in views template list ! However, the generated view is not working, I get the following error :

> \Drupal\calendar\Plugin\views\style\CalendarStyle: A calendar date argument is required when using the calendar style, but it is missing or is not using the default date.

Comment: I assume you have `"views_data" = "Drupal\views\EntityViewsData"` in your entity. But this doesn't help for a datatime basefield, because of this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2489476, so you need a hook_view_data, see #9 in this issue.

Answer (score 3):

`EntityViewsData` provides the information for views for entity types, so that they are included in views. For datetime basefields this is not working at the moment, because of this issue https://www.drupal.org/node/2489476. So you need to provide the data in a `hook_views_data` or by extending `EntityViewsData`. From the documentation:

> - argument: Specifies a handler to make it available to Views as an   argument, or contextual filter as it is known in the UI.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21views%21views.api.php/function/hook_views_data/8.3.x

You've mentioned that you have a working example if you use a field configured in UI, so you could try to copy the views data.

Comment: I tried this, it makes the field to appear in views template, but I get another error (see updated question), maybe I need to define more things in my EntityViewsData class ?

Comment: This is where #9 of the issue ends, it doesn't say which view data you should provide, it only has an example for another field type. But you could place both a base and a UI configured (bundle) datetime field in the entity and compare the views_data (which is one big array). And if you've found it add the information to the issue.

Comment: The field is accessible in views, as field, filter sort. However I still have the same error when I try to make a calendar view.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in

namespace Drupal\kabukis_tests\Entity;
use Drupal\views\EntityViewsData;

```
class TestEntityViewsData extends EntityViewsData {
  public function getViewsData() {
    $additionalData = [
      'test_date' => [
        'title' => new TranslatableMarkup('Birth date'),
        'help' => new TranslatableMarkup('Birth date'),
        'field' => [ 'id' => 'field' ],
   ...
```

You have to write :

```
...'field' => [ 'id' => 'date' ],...
```

according to the documentation in api.drupal.org of hook_views_data()(it is the same returned format of data like in this class).